# cannot setState using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

```
componentDidMount() {
  var self = this;

  axios.get('http://URL')
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      this.setState({
        data: response.data
      })
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I got this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Use `self` instead of `this` if you don't use arrow function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow function so that you no need to depend on local variable and scope will be taken care automatically

```
 componentDidMount(){
     axios.get('http://URL')
         .then( response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            this.setState({data: response.data})
     })
    .catch(error =>  {
        console.log(error);
   });
 }
```

Or replace this with self while doing setState like below

```
  componentDidMount(){
      var self = this;
      axios.get('http://URL')
         .then(function (response) {
             console.log(response.data);
             self.setState({data: response.data})
     })
    .catch(function (error) {
       console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Both the above options will work. I would recommend you to go with first option

Answer (score 0):

If you use `self` instead of `this` on setState should fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 arrow function that automagically binds lexical parent scope for you.

```
componentDidMount(){
     axios.get('http://URL')
         .then( response => {
            console.log(response.data);

            this.setState({
                data: response.data
            })
     })
    .catch(error =>  {
        console.log(error);
   });
 }
```

Introducing `self` is overkill and comes from jQuery. It was used before ES6 arrow function been introduced.

You can read about auto `this` binding in arrow functions here:

https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4

Also check those links to better understand how `this` works in Javascript and the logic of scope:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript
https://javascriptplayground.com/javascript-variable-scope-this/

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the `this` context problem and use this alternative. Since Axios returns a promise, you can use **async/await**, and don't think about the `this` context.

Use it like this:

```
async function getData(url){
    try {
        return await axios.get(url);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async componentDidMount(){
    let response = await getData('http://URL');
    console.log(response.data);
    this.setState({data: response.data});
 }
```

Looks more readable and easier to use for other functions and components as well.